# Jenkins: The test is running fine but the chrome driver does not open

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I am trying to run a maven project which contains a testng file from jenkins.

In the jenkins build i am using mvn clean test running from cmd.

The test is executing fine and i am seeing the log in the jenkins console. But the chrome driver does not open.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 18265
Only local connections are allowed.
```

How do i add the ip from which jenkins is running to the chromedriver whitelist?

Comment: ChromeDriver is starting on the machine where the tests are being executed. So having only local connections accepted is okay. You're saying the chromedriver is not opening but at the same time you show the log of chromedriver saying that it has opened and is running..

Comment: Yes. I am trying to run a selenium test through a jenkins build. The chromedriver opens and I am able to see the logs in the jenkins console. But the browser does not open. I need the browser to open as well to view the flow execution.